# Installing SSMS on TFS 2010 server

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs, ssms

I've just installed, configured and tested trial installation of TFS 2010. Everything works fine, but.. I want to be able to see database structure and data of the TFS server. My first thought was obvious: SQL Server Management Studio (I've noticed that SQL Server 2008 was installed during the TFS 2010 installation process).

Now, to the point. I've tried to install SSMS exactly as desribed [HERE](http://www.2008hosting.net/MicrosoftSQL/Management_Studio_Express_2008.aspx), but there is an additional step between point 7 and 8. Let's name it 7a. In this step I have to choose between "performing a new installation of SQL Server 2008" and "adding features to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008".

The problem is that if I choose "adding features to an existing instance" there is no SSMS tool checkbox in later steps.

Why?

**UPDATE:**

I had choosen "new installation" and installed SSMS. It works. No new instance was created. Still I don't understand what is the reason of splitting these options..

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe I've run into this before. Can you try selecting "Perform a new installation...". I don't believe you'll have to actually create a new instance, but it should let you install SSMS.

Comment: Yes, I know that if i choose "new installation" it allows me to choose SSMS tool, but I don't understand what's the difference here? Will it create new instance of SQL Server? Or is it just "not so obvious" way to add SSMS to an existing instance?

Comment: I believe it's the "not so obvious" way to add SSMS. Feel free to post a screenshot of the next screen once you select "new installation" to confirm.

Comment: That's exactly what I was suspecting. Now I'm 90% sure that if you proceed the only action will be that SSMS will be installed, but if you've got data in that instance, I'd be more comfortable hearing from another source before proceeding.

Comment: Data is not a problem. The server is on my learning and testing virtual machine and I can always make a snapshot. The reason I've created this question is that I am just curios. Why the installation process is split but do the same thing. Maybe it's really simple and somebody knows "why".

Comment: I'd be interested as well, but sadly unless we get a developer that worked on this install, we'll probably never know. I'd say go ahead with your process a few more "Next" clicks and you should be home free.